Why does the model disappear in Cycles render view?
It was working, but I must have hit some button because now it's gone. Here is what I mean when I press Render for Cycles in viewport:



please disregard the arrows in first pic, it was for something else

If you don't need your original question then you should delete that post. You can also edit your post to get rid of unwanted text or images.

No i need the question, I was saying the arrows in the first pic please disregard, I uploaded it because to show that the render worked a second ago. I cant take another pic to show what render looked like because well, its gone now XD

Also please let me know if theres any info that could help to figure this out, I dont know what to look for so please let me know!

Hello, please provide more information about your issue. We can't help if we don't know what the problem is. :)

In the first screenshot and on the second screenshot's right viewport we don't see the light objects, yet they are here in in the second screenshot's left viewport. Is your viewport on the left side actually placed to see the mesh object in the first place?

Hi lock, yes its placed i can take a screenshot too but the only time the mesh on L disspears is when i switch to render in viewport (Cycles)
The reason the light objects dissapeared is because I did the "Hide extras" view

Here i uploaded the blendfile to gdrive, it think maybe this would be easeier to see.https://drive.google.com/file/d/18du21tVwhXDJTcRfFie530rCG3Z8Fm7F/view?usp=sharing

You could have deleted the hidden objects and collections that are useless in this case and saved as a compressed file to have a 1.39MB file to share on Blend-Exchange, instead of having to move around a 135MB file on gdrive. That would have saved a lot of time to many people.

Apologies Lock im still unaware of alot of things like this, could you point me in how I could do that? is it an option under File or in preferences?

Woah lock, i think i found a solution by accident.
I applied the multiRes modifier in Object mode to object, then I pressed Undo.
Now i can stil have multires modifier while in sculpt mode and Cycles render works....woah check this this out

https://ibb.co/Yjs6ZXH

Nvm, I tried it again and didnt work, i think its cus sculpt base mesh was checked, thanks Lock lol

The issue seems to come from the Multires Modifier and only in sculpt mode. I'm not sure why it happens, and it seems to be a known bug:
#67026 - Cycles does not render geo with Multires modifier while in Sculpt mode - blender - Blender Projects
Switching out of sculpt mode or enabling Sculpt Base Mesh makes it renderable again, but don't leave the latter enabled at all time while sculpting if you don't want it.
